# Leave deduction in payroll section of OpenERP

Tags: python, odoo

I am working with payroll module of OpenERP and going mad with the following error.

This is what i have tried:

1. Created a unpaid leave in Leave Type and selected a payroll head 'LOP' and created an Analytic account for the same
2. An employee requested for this unpaid leave from 'Leave Request Section'
3. While calculating the payslip for that employee,the leaves and the leave deductions are shown are calculated and displayed in the payslip.

but when i am trying to approve the payslip,i am getting the error:

```
ProgrammingError: operator does not exist: integer = boolean
LINE 1: ...d FROM "account_account" WHERE account_account.id IN (false)...
                                                             ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

This occurs only when I select 'unpaid' leave in 'leave type' section.

Comment: I see you reported a bug on [launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/openobject-addons/+bug/944723). You should probably list which modules you have installed, and you might want to give more details in your scenario so people can try to reproduce it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally i found the solution to the question..

The issue  occurred when the account corresponding to the LOP is entered into db as `False`.

To resolve the problem,just select a `General Account` for the `LOP` row in the 
`salary structure` tab of Payslip.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this python code :

```
try:
    result = -(contract.wage /31 ) * worked_days.Unpaid.number_of_days
except : 
    result = 0
```